# What is the current scientific consensus regarding the relationship between Eukaryotes and Archaea?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology, microbiology, archaea

In the traditional 3-domain system, the domains Bacteria, Archaea, and Eukaryota are all distinct from one another, with the latter 2 usually being sister-groups in a clade.

However recent evidence has come to light showing that Eukaryotes might have arose ***within*** Archaea, rather than being the sister group to it. More specifically, Eukaryotes might have evolved from the [Asgard archaean superphylum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asgard_(archaea)).

What is the current consensus towards this issue? Do most evolutionary scientists today still consider Eukaryotes to be the sister group to Archea? Or is it thought that eukaryotes **are** archaeans?

Comment: What makes you think that there is a consensus on any controversy in science, and what makes you think that knowing which view is dominant has any importance per se. As scientists, we on this list are only interested in the strengths and weaknesses of arguments. Please present your questions in these terms.

Comment: For a recent provocative article on this subject, see [Isolation of an archaeon at the prokaryote-eukaryote interface](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31942073/), and see also [The mysterious microbes that gave rise to complex life](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01316-0) (both articles published in Nature in 2021)